# I want to show data in grid format iPad

Tags: ios

In my application I have to show data in grid like Asp.net gridControl.I want following features

1. Sorting on multiple column
2. Filtering on multiple column
3. Editable data, update data.
4. Resizing Column width.
5. Filtering between 2 dates

Have any example which meet my requirements.

Thanks

Comment: Try UICollectionView for your app.

Comment: Apple provide [UICollectionview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) read this and implement.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Comment: Pankaj : i need already made control like nuclios or infragistics type.

Comment: Check Asp.net grid control. i want all features like it. This control you can add any type of column like date, popover, textfield. Resizing column, hide column etc.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS SDK `UICollectionView` can be used as Grid View. Using `UICollectionView` along with search bar sorting, filtering can be achieved.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use UICollectionView or try to use some already made controls

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/tags/grid